# Extracting information from a sentence using NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, information-extraction

I want to extract information from sentences. I am a newbie in this field. I have sentences as :

```
    "Andrew query pizza king what is today's deal"
 "Andrew order flower shop to send my wife roses"
Format : <Name> <command> <company name> <connecting word> <action>
```

With the help of standford NLP parser how to extract the sentences as the format above? Like After extracting If i want to print action of the sentence it should give `{is today's deal, me send my wife roses}`

Answer (score 1):

That's a hard task. If you have a very, very restricted set of sentences you can try to use the [parser dependencies](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf) and model your problem with rules. However, I ran your sentence through the [Stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) and got obviously wrong result:

```
(ROOT
  (FRAG
    (NP
      (NP (NNP Andrew) (NN query) (NN pizza) (NN king))
      (SBAR
        (WHNP (WP what))
        (S
          (VP (VBZ is)
            (NP
              (NP (NN today) (POS 's))
              (NN deal))))))))
```

As you can see, it sees Andrew query pizza king as a noun phrase, it would do the same with "Andrew dog carrot soup what is today's deal". Obviously it misses the verb "query", the target "pizza king", etc.

Even if that worked, the syntax parser models only syntax, ignoring semantics. You should check [Semantic Role Labeling](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/22.pdf), Named Entity Recognition, Relation Extraction, etc. For your specific task most probably you would have to define your own semantics, then use a statistical algorithm for analyzing the text and extracting the needed information.

Here is a nice article about approaches to building chatbots: https://techinsight.com.vn/language/en/three-basic-nlp-problems-one-develops-chatbot-system-typical-approaches/

Comment: Visitor from the future. The Stanford Parser link is dead. However, you can find the home page for the project [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml).